# How to insert json_data in the influxdb v1.8.4

Tags: python, influxdb

I am trying to insert a json_body in the influxdb. But I am getting an error Unable to parse the data.`Invalid format Error code 400`.

Here is my code:

```
from influxdb import InfluxDBClient
import json, ast

def insertFeedData(feed, sensorType):
   client = InfluxDBClient(host='localhost', port=8086)
   write_command = 'mqtt_feed,feed=' + feed + ' sensor_type='+  str(sensorType) +',sensor_id=' + str(sensorType)
   print(write_command)
   client.write([write_command],{'db':'SmartRural_feed'},204,'line')
   client.close()


feed = '{"end_device_ids":{"device_id":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX","application_ids":{"application_id":"digitalmatter-oyster-01"},"dev_eui":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX","join_eui":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX","dev_addr":"XXXXXXXXX"},"correlation_ids":["as:up:XXXXXXXXXXXX","gs:conn:XXXXXXXXXXXXXX","gs:up:host:01F1C1P1F46RM6Q2H5GSBF9V7E","gs:uplink:01F1CCHXF6SBFA50HJCHPVAN7X","ns:uplink:XXXXXXXXXXXX","rpc:/ttn.lorawan.v3.GsNs/HandleUplink:01F1CCHXF8YQKMFRKMNWSKC6GK","rpc:/ttn.lorawan.v3.NsAs/HandleUplink:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"],"received_at":"2021-03-22T07:14:29.051626349Z","uplink_message":{"session_key_id":"AXhFTz+fm9aPrK/fzAbGoQ==","f_port":1,"f_cnt":361,"frm_payload":"XXXXXXXXX","decoded_payload":{"aamsg_type":"position","battV":4.675,"fixok":True,"heading":0,"intrip":False,"lat":57.4510524,"lon":-2.9442034,"speedKmph":0},"rx_metadata":[{"gateway_ids":{"gateway_id":"05-0008","eui":"FCC23DFFFE20F3AC"},"timestamp":743687252,"rssi":-97,"channel_rssi":-97,"snr":9.5,"location":{"source":"SOURCE_REGISTRY"},"uplink_token":"XXXXXX","channel_index":7}],"settings":{"data_rate":{"lora":{"bandwidth":125000,"spreading_factor":7}},"data_rate_index":5,"coding_rate":"4/5","frequency":"867900000","timestamp":743687252},"received_at":"2021-03-22T07:14:28.460612285Z","consumed_airtime":"0.061696s"}}'

feed_dict = ast.literal_eval(feed)

insertFeedData(str(feed_dict), 2)
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. I have also thought of inserting the data in this format.

```
json_body = [
        {
            "measurement": "mqtt_feed",
            "tags": {
                "host": "server01",
                "region": "us-west"
            },
            "time": "2009-11-10T23:00:00Z",
            "fields": {
                "value": 0.64
            }
        }
    ]
```

But here I am getting an error. Database is required. Though I have used `client.write_database('db')`. Can Any suggestions will be of great help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
client = InfluxDBClient(host='localhost', port=8086)
client.switch_database('db')#your db name
client.write_points(json_body)
```

Try and use the above code.